# Graphite - create graph with percentage

Tags: monitoring, graphite

I am trying to create a graph as show below which was described in blog post(http://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2013/06/26/practical-guide-to-graphite-monitoring/)

[image: what im looking for]

However I cannot get the values to "stack" on top of each other. They are overlapping each other.
My example:

[image: My example]

The is my graph data:

[image]

Graph after using "stacked" - not quite what I was looking for
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were fairly close to it. :)

In the Graphite web-app, follow `Graph Options -> Line Mode -> Stacked`.
In case you're rendering using the API, add `&areaMode=stacked` to your URL.

---

This is the GUI tweak to achieve what you want. To *generate* the metrics, do-

```
asPercent(
      group(
             carbon.agents.ip-10-0-0-111-a.updateOperations,
             carbon.agents.ip-10-0-0-111-a.metricsReceived
      ),
      sumSeries(
             carbon.agents.ip-10-0-0-111-a.updateOperations,
             carbon.agents.ip-10-0-0-111-a.metricsReceived
      )
)
```

## This is how it works-

`asPercent` takes *two* arguments- a `seriesList` and a `total`. Here, the `group(...)` part is the former and `sumSeries(...)` the latter. Graphite compares each metric in the `seriesList` ( which can be achieved by `group()` or by using wildcards) with the total and hence calculates percentages.

The good part is that `total` is an optional and if not sent is assumed to be the total of `seriesList`. So in essence, your metric is reduced to-

```
asPercent(
      group(
             carbon.agents.ip-10-0-0-111-a.updateOperations,
             carbon.agents.ip-10-0-0-111-a.metricsReceived
      )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks erbdex. Have tried what you suggested (see update image in question). However not quiet what I has looking for. The "blue" metric is the overall (100 %), so I want to see the breakdown of the three metrics to make up the 100%. Any idea how to do this?